# Conditional table updates

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Consider the following table.

```
myTable
+----+-----------+------------------------------------+
| Id | responseA |             responseB              |
+----+-----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 |           | {"foo":"bar","lvl2":{"key":"val"}} |
+----+-----------+------------------------------------+
```

where:

```
Id, INT (11) PRIMARY
responseA, TEXT utf8_unicode_ci
responseB, TEXT utf8_unicode_ci
```

Let's say that I want to ***conditionally*** update the table with some outside data. The conditions are:

• if there's nothing in `responseA`, populate it with the outside data, **otherwise**

• if there ***is*** something in `responseA`, leave it as it is, and populate `responseB` with the outside data

I was pretty much convinced that I could just do this to get what I want:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET
    responseA = IF(TRIM(responseA) = '','foo',TRIM(responseA)),
    responseB = IF(TRIM(responseA) != '','foo',TRIM(responseB))
WHERE Id = 1
```

However, this updates both `responseA` and `responseB` to the same value - `foo`, making the table:

```
myTable
+----+-----------+-----------+
| Id | responseA | responseB |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |    foo    |    foo    |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I was expecting my table to look like this after the update:

```
myTable
+----+-----------+------------------------------------+
| Id | responseA |             responseB              |
+----+-----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 |    foo    | {"foo":"bar","lvl2":{"key":"val"}} |
+----+-----------+------------------------------------+
```

What am I misunderstanding, and how can I achieve this conditional update? Do the updates happen sequentially? If so, I guess that would explain why both of the fields are updated.

Comment: change the if condition to **IF( TRIM(responseA) = '' OR  responseA IS NULL, 0, 1) **

Comment: @BerndBuffen Apologies, I failed to mention that the fields can only have non-null values, that's why there was no explicit testing for that.

Comment: OK - you also must change the the IF lines, else the first if is checked AND then set responseA to foo. after this mysql will test the second if and see that responseA isent "" , so it will set responseB. now both are set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here your changed query

```
UPDATE myTable
SET
    responseB = IF(TRIM(responseA) != '','foo',TRIM(responseB)),
    responseA = IF(TRIM(responseA) = '','foo',TRIM(responseA))
WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: Right, that seems to have done the trick, and it does address the original issue. Too bad that it's not easily scalable, though.

Comment: @FiddlingAway - Post a short sample via http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2):

```sql
UPDATE TABLE
SET responseA = CASE WHEN responseA IS NULL
                     THEN @data
                     ELSE responseA
                     END,
    responseB = CASE WHEN responseA IS NULL
                     THEN responseB 
                     ELSE @data
                     END
;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the value of responseA is changed before the `IF()` for responseB is evaluated.

One possible solution is to do a simple UPDATE:

```
UPDATE mytable SET responseA = ? WHERE id = 1
```

Then adjust the columns in a trigger, where you have access to both the original and the new value of the columns:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF TRIM(OLD.responseA) != '' THEN
    SET NEW.responseB = NEW.responseA;
    SET NEW.responseA = OLD.responseA;
  END IF;
END
```

(I have not tested this.)

I am also assuming that your test for `''` (empty string) instead of NULL is deliberate, and that you know that NULL is not the same as `''`.

Comment: "I am also assuming that your test for `''` (empty string) instead of NULL is deliberate" - Exactly, the columns can only hold non-null values (everything defaults to `''`), that's why there was no `NULL` testing involved.

Answer (score 1):

The key point in the `UPDATE` statement is that you should update first the column `responseB`, so that column `responseA` retains its original value which can be checked again when you try to update it:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET responseB = CASE WHEN TRIM(responseA) = '' THEN responseB ELSE 'foo' END,
    responseA = CASE WHEN TRIM(responseA) = '' THEN 'foo' ELSE responseA END
WHERE Id = 1;
```